# How to use native spreadsheet functions in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

Is it possible to use native spreadsheet functions such as sum() or today() in google apps script, when writing code for google Spreadsheet? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Apps Script is JavaScript, spreadsheets functions are not available and using a workaround like `setFormula` followed by `getValue` is not only cumbersome but really slow and inefficient. You will be better inspired to use JavaScript and Google services to manipulate data taken from a spreadsheet and write the data back in one single `setValues()`.

Answer (score 25):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
cell.setFormula("=SUM(B3:B4)");
```

Comment: Thank you.It's helpful.

Comment: Agree with Serge's answer that it will be slow and inefficient, but some functionality is VERY expensive to reimplement.  Like `query`, so sometimes these gymnastics are indeed necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Also might be good to refer to this article about using Javascript objects to read and write to cells.  I can't think of any good reason for using functions in VBA or Apps Script unless they are doing so indirectly through reading a cell value.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading