# Are Google sheets math functions available in scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google sheets scripts

Example:

1. `Varxx = Math.floor(3.4)` //works with JavaScript Math method
2. `Varxx = INT(3.4)` // Does not work ...

> ReferenceError: "INT" is not defined.

I would like access to the other functions that are available in Google sheets, so how to make approach 2. work? Or what primer/tutorial should I be reading?

Comment: I think you'll find this question addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234912/how-to-use-native-spreadsheet-functions-in-google-apps-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using built-in spreadsheet functions in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660574/using-built-in-spreadsheet-functions-in-a-script)

Comment: Thanks. That answers it (the answer is 'no'). I searched but somehow didn't find these threads. The available Javascript functions will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Google apps script is predominantly Javascript.

I don't think google sheet formulas are available in google apps script but (almost) all the javascript functionalities are available, so we can use those.

For example :

> Google Sheet INT equivalent in javascript is Math.floor

```js
console.log(Math.floor(3.4))
```

As mentioned in another answer, we can use parseInt also.

```js
console.log(parseInt(3.4))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also cast with parse

```
varxx = parseInt(variable)
```