# Can I call native functions from within a script in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

E.g.  I have a script.

Is there a way from within the script that I can use the top level interface functions like SUM() and AVERAGE() -- the things that people use to write formulas;

Alternately does each one of these have a corresponding internal script function.

Link to documentation for either of these appreciated.  My google-fu so far has failed.

---

Voting to close my own question.

This is a duplicate of two questions:

- [Using built-in spreadsheet functions in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660574/using-built-in-spreadsheet-functions-in-a-script)

and

- [How to use native spreadsheet functions in google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234912/how-to-use-native-spreadsheet-functions-in-google-apps-script)

The short answer (since this won't get an answer once it gets a well deserved close vote)

- Not presently in the google API.
- There are kludge ways around it, but they are slow and inefficient.

I was hoping that I could use google sheets scripting like I use perl to glue and parse unix commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using built-in spreadsheet functions in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660574/using-built-in-spreadsheet-functions-in-a-script)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use native spreadsheet functions in google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234912/how-to-use-native-spreadsheet-functions-in-google-apps-script) It explains that although there are alternatives to do this, it is inefficient and not recommended. The best thing to do is to learn how to do the operations with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you.  I am adding these two references to my question and requesting it be closed.