# How to use native Google Sheets formulas in Google Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sparklines

I am struggling trying to create a formula that results in an array to feed the formula sparkline(). How can I call formulas into the script? So far I have:

```
 function historic(term) {

var data = '=index(split(split(IMPORTXML('https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/'"&term&"'/historical_data/usd/','//td[3]'),' '),'$'),0,0)';



  var timelineData=data["default"].timelineData;
  for (var i in timelineData) {
    var tdata=timelineData[i];
    resp.push(tdata.value[0]);
  }
  return resp;
}

function testHistoric(){
  historic("mobfish");
}
```

Comment: You can not see this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234912/how-to-use-native-spreadsheet-functions-in-google-apps-script

Comment: thanks for your feedback. The problem is that I am trying to create a function, in the script example you shared, the result is in a specific cell. All the examples that I have found have a similar approach. I am not sure how to do it for a formula.

Comment: The native Google Spreadsheet formula has to be in the spreadsheet you can not run it from app script.  Assuming the formula has executed and the sheet populated with values you can use getValues() to get data from the spreadsheet and setValues() to put results back.  I have provide a link to getValues() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues() and setValues() is on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

### by formula

You got an error while writing the formula because of the mix between `'` and `"`. Use instead [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
It could be

```
function historic(term) {
  var formula = `=index(split(split(IMPORTXML("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/${term}/historical_data/usd/","//td[3]")," "),"$"),0,0)`;
  return formula;
}
function testHistoric() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setFormula(historic("bitcoin"));
}
```

[image]

You can use [coingecko api](https://blog.coingecko.com/import-coingecko-cryptocurrency-data-into-google-sheets/)

Or use this formula

```
=importhtml("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin/historical_data/usd","table",1)
```

[image]

### edit: by script

If you want to fetch the informations by script and not by formula, try

```
function testHistoric() {
  historic("bitcoin")
}
function historic(term) {
  url = `https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/${term}/historical_data/usd/`;
  var html = '<table' + UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"").match(/(?<=\<table).*(?=\<\/table)/g) + '</table>';
  var trs = [...html.matchAll(/<tr[\s\S\w]+?<\/tr>/g)];
  var data = [];
  for (var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
    var tds = [...trs[i][0].matchAll(/<(td|th)[\s\S\w]+?<\/(td|th)>/g)];
    var prov = [];
    for (var j=0;j<tds.length;j++){
      donnee=tds[j][0].match(/(?<=\>).*(?=\<\/)/g)[0];
      prov.push((donnee));
    }
    data.push(prov);
  }
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
}
```

Comment: thanks, a valid term would be "bitcoin". I have tried your script and it returns the string but does not evaluate the formula

Comment: it works with bitcoin

Comment: if you use the function historic("bitcoin") do you get the results in the sheet?

Comment: The subject is not the same; here you asked how using a formula and I give you the way to write it. I will know show you how to use UrlFetchApp.fetch

Comment: See edit chapter

Comment: thanks a lot, I think this is what I am looking for. I tried your script and I get the message:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
historic @ historic.gs:19

Comment: which term do you use in historic(term) ? pleae provide your spreadsheet. It works fine on my sode!

Comment: it works! I am not sure why it was stuck. thanks a lot!